# How to put value parameter same as option parameter in Dash Python

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I try to make a map visualization with bunch of filter using Dash. My Dash component in this case is using DMC or [Dash Mantine Component](https://www.dash-mantine-components.com/). I tried to build something like 'chaining callback' which the the first multiselect will be affecting second multiselect option. Here is what I've got

[image]

and then if you change the 'Block Name' input, it will affect the availability option in 'Operator Name' which second multiselect component

[image]

Now the problem is, how do I put default value in "operator name" input, so everytime I reload the page, the "operator name" will input the available option. Something like this when I reload the page

[image]

It set the default value. How do I do that in Dash Mantine Component?
Here's my code so far

```
html.Div(
    className='accordion-content',
    children=[

html.H5('Block Name', style={'marginTop':20}),
dmc.MultiSelect(
    placeholder="Select Block Name",
    id="multiselect-block",
    value=all_blocks['Block_Name'].to_list(),
    data=all_blocks['Block_Name'].to_list(),
    style={'marginTop':10},
    clearable=True,
    searchable=True,
    nothingFound= 'No Options Found'
    ),

html.H5('Operator Name', style={'marginTop':20}),
dmc.MultiSelect(
    placeholder="Select Operator Name",
    id="multiselect-operator",
    value=[], #here is the problem, I dont know how to set the value here
    data=[],
    style={'marginTop':10},
    clearable=True,
    searchable=True,
    nothingFound= 'No Options Found'
    )

@app.callback(
    Output('multiselect-operator', 'data'),
    Input('multiselect-block', 'value')
)

def set_operator_option(chosen_block):
    if chosen_block is None:
        df_operator=[]
    else:
        df_operator = all_blocks[all_blocks['Block_Name'].isin(chosen_block)]
    return pd.unique(df_operator['Operator'].to_list())
```

Comment: Can you post sample dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think first of all you should add Operator value and then return new value based on callback. Something like below:

```
import dash_mantine_components as dmc
from dash import Dash, Input, Output, html, dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'process': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
        'code': [f'CODE{i}' for i in range(1, 7)],
        'data': [1 for _ in range(6)]
    }
)

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    className='accordion-content',
    children=[

html.H5('Block Name', style={'marginTop':20}),
dmc.MultiSelect(
    placeholder="Select Block Name",
    id="multiselect-block",
    value=df['process'].unique(),
    data=df['process'].unique(),
    style={'marginTop':10},
    clearable=True,
    searchable=True,
    nothingFound= 'No Options Found'
    ),

html.H5('Operator Name', style={'marginTop':20}),
dmc.MultiSelect(
    placeholder="Select Operator Name",
    id="multiselect-operator",
    value=df['code'].unique(), #here is the problem, I dont know how to set the value here
    data=df['code'].unique(),
    style={'marginTop':10},
    clearable=True,
    searchable=True,
    nothingFound= 'No Options Found'
    )
    ])

@app.callback(
    Output('multiselect-operator', 'data'),
    Input('multiselect-block', 'value')
)

def set_operator_option(chosen_block):
    if chosen_block is None:
        df2=df.copy
    else:
        df2 = df[df['process'].isin(chosen_block)]
    return pd.unique(df2['code'].to_list())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False, port = 1514)
```

- First load:
  [image]
- After removing first selection:
  [image]